# Process stdin, stdout, and stderr redirection cause `read ECONNRESET`

Tags: node.js, subprocess, child-process, io-redirection

I build a terminal application using Node.Js child_process to run other process. The application need to execute other terminal application (subprocess) that can be interactive. When I test it, most times I encounters `read ECONNRESET`, but in few times it runs successfully.

The following is part of my code that yield error:

```
import {exec} from "child_process";
const command = "(echo 5 && echo 7) | python3 add.py 5 7";
// or: const command = "python3 add.py";
const subProcess = exec(command, options, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    return reject(error);
  }
  return resolve(stdout);
});

process.stdin.on("data", stdinListener);
subProcess.stdin.on("end", () => {
  process.stdin.removeListener("data", stdinListener);
  process.stdin.end();
});

subProcess.stdout.on("data", (chunk) => {
  process.stderr.write("\x1b[33m" + String(chunk) + "\x1b[0m");
});

subProcess.stderr.on("data", (chunk) => {
  process.stderr.write("\x1b[31m" + String(chunk) + "\x1b[0m");
});

function stdinListener(chunk) {
  subProcess.stdin.write(chunk);
}
```

Basically, I apply `on data` listener to `subProcess.stdout` and `subProcess.stdin`. Thus, every output of `subProcess` will also shown in the main process (as `stderr`).

I also apply `on data` listener to `process.stdin`, thus the user can use `process.stdin` to interact with subProcess.

For the sake of simplicity, I put this command example: `(echo 5 && echo 7) | python3 add.py 5 7`. I need to do this because `add.py` might run with arguments (i.e: `python3 add.py 5 7`), or interactively. It is even possible for the user to just run `python3 add.py`.

This is not web application, and will only run locally. So there will be little or no security threat.

The error is as follow (and it doesn't always shown):

```
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at _errnoException (util.js:992:11)
    at Pipe.onread (net.js:618:25)
```

It is really frustrating because the error doesn't occurred all the time.

I don't really get any idea about what's wrong. But I suspect these might be the case:

- The execution was so fast, it is finished before `subProcess` redirection even started.
- `process.stdin` might not the best way to stop `subProcess`'s stdin. But I need to end this up because I don't want my application to wait forever, even after subProcess ended.

Does anybody know the solution?

**Note:** The code is here, and actually it is typescript: https://github.com/goFrendiAsgard/chiml/blob/7065b57ba24d73c29dd54a28f9f7c9ebbf0fb269/src/libraries/cmd.ts

**Edit (workaround):** I found a very weird workaround by adding `on error` listener to both `process.stdin` and `subprocess.stdin` since I see some `Unhandled error` message in my `jest` testing. This is how I add the listeners:

```
subProcess.stdin.on("error", (error) => console.error(error));
process.stdin.on("error", (error) => console.error(error));
```

So far it works without any failure (I will update if the same error occurred).